# Published & monetized apps on the Google Play Store using GitHub libraries licensed under "BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License" and "Apache License 2.0"

Tags: copyright

I slightly modified some libraries from [GitHub](https://github.com/), published them in the form of apps on the Google Play Store and monetized them.

The libraries are licensed under "BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License" and "Apache License 2.0".

According to my understanding of both of these licenses: I am allowed to modify, publish (even in the form of apps) and monetize as I did without any consequences. But, just to be sure, my questions are the following:

- Is my understanding correct?
- And do I need to perform any extra procedures to be fully compliant with these licenses? The screenshots below mention the "license and copyright notice" and "state changes" conditions. It is not really clear how that would be applied in my case (if it needs to be applied); can someone please advise?

The following is how the libraries' licenses look like in GitHub:

[image]

[image]

I would really appreciate your guidance and please don't hesitate to ask for more details. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes, your understanding is correct that you can use libraries under those licenses in your monetized app.

> And do I need to perform any extra procedures to be fully compliant with these licenses? The screenshots below mention the "license and copyright notice" and "state changes" conditions. It is not really clear how that would be applied in my case (if it needs to be applied); can someone please advise?

To comply with the licenses, you must inform the users of your app that it contains code that is subject to the 2-clause BSD or the Apache 2.0 license and you need to reproduce the license text.

Preferably, this information is shown in a screen that also contains your copyright and licensing information.

If you want to create goodwill with the open source community, you not just mention that "some code" is under those open source licenses, but you actually name the libraries and under which license they are.

Neither the BSD nor the Apache license has a requirement for distributing source code, so you don't have to do anything in that respect.